Why http.server does not deliver the data to the CGI script in this basic example?
I am testing the legacy CGI functionality of python http.server module by implementing a "hello world" alike example that sends data from a fictional "add customer" form from the web front end to the backend.
The data is processed by a CGI script which just writes the text received into a file.
This is what I have tried:
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add New Customer</title>
    <script>
        function submitForm() {

            // Test string to send
            fixedLengthData = "FOO TEST STRING";

            // Post to console
            console.log(fixedLengthData);

            // Create and send POST request to COBOL backend
            fetch('/cgi-bin/customer_add', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                },
                body: fixedLengthData
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
                }
                return response;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add New Customer</h1>
    <form id="customerForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); submitForm();">
        <label for="CUSTOMER-ID">Customer ID:</label>
        <input type="text" id="CUSTOMER-ID" name="CUSTOMER-ID" maxlength="4" required><br>
        <label for="CUSTOMER-NAME">Customer Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="CUSTOMER-NAME" name="CUSTOMER-NAME" maxlength="50" required><br>
        <label for="CUSTOMER-EMAIL">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="CUSTOMER-EMAIL" name="CUSTOMER-EMAIL" maxlength="100"><br>
        
        <button type="submit">Add Customer</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


This is the backend CGI script located under cgi-bin folder:
#!/bin/sh

# Open the file 'test.txt' for writing
exec 3> test.txt

# Read all input from stdin into a single variable
input=$(cat)

# Write the input to the file
echo "$input" >&3

# Close the file
exec 3>&-

Running the http.server and accessing the CGI script at the browser gets the CGI script launched but:

it never ends and
writes nothing to the text file

I am wondering if it could be that no data is provided to the CGI script in the standard input or the script not finishing makes the data written to file not being flushed.
$ python3 -m http.server --bind localhost --cgi 8000
Serving HTTP on ::1 port 8000 (http://[::1]:8000/) ...
::1 - - [30/Aug/2024 02:39:27] "POST /cgi-bin/customer_add HTTP/1.1" 200 -

ps shows that the CGI process does not end.
$ ps

user 24194   0.0  0.0    13556    2644 10  S+   02:39       0:00.00 /bin/sh /home/user/test/cgi-bin/customer_add


The CGI script itself seems to work as stand alone:
$ echo -n "FOO TEST STRING" | ./customer_add
$ ls -ltr
total 64
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user    209 Aug 30 02:37 customer_add
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user      4 Aug 30 02:37 test.txt
$ cat test.txt
FOO TEST STRING

Why the CGI process gets stuck, could it be that it is not receiving the data?

Does the bash work if you do write a newline echo "FOO TEST STRING" | ./customer_add

Yes it does. After some debugging it seems that http.server does not generate EOF after sending the data, which gets the CGI script stuck until timeout. At the timeout everything appears normal because the CGI script completes its task.
If you use another web server (I tried with althttpd) this does not happen and you get a normal response from the script.
This is not a bug since it seems that in the CGI specification the EOF "MAY" be issued by the server but it is not a "MUST".

It may be because you didn't send back http response back to the server after writing operation is done. you can modify your CGI script something like this:
#!/bin/sh

# Output the necessary HTTP headers
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

# Open the file 'test.txt' for writing
exec 3> test.txt

# Read all input from stdin into a single variable
input=$(cat)

# Write the input to the file
echo "$input" >&3

# Close the file
exec 3>&-


It is not and the proposed answer does not fix the issue. The reason being likely the one described in the original post's comments.
